# ValueError: Found array with dim 4. SVC expected <= 2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, svm

I am trying to train a model for predicting hand written digits, were the camera captures the image of the digit and the model predicts but, i keep getting the value error of the title above. Here are my codes.

The image is recized as in the line * img_resized = cv2.resize(im_binary,(28,28))* but I think it is wrong done, can you help me figure out the correct way of doing it, since the image captured bu the camera can not be received.

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets

svc=svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)

digits=datasets.load_digits()
x=digits['data']
y=digits['target']



svc.fit(x,y)



import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage import img_as_ubyte    
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

width = 640
height = 480
cameraNo = 0
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraNo)
cap.set(3,width)
cap.set(4,height)




while True:
    success, img_orig = cap.read()
    img_gray = rgb2gray(img_orig)
    img_gray_u8 = img_as_ubyte(img_gray)
    (thresh, im_binary) = cv2.threshold(img_gray_u8, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    img_resized = cv2.resize(im_binary,(28,28))
    im_gray_invert = 255 - img_resized
    cv2.imshow("invert image", im_gray_invert)
    im_final = im_gray_invert.reshape(1,28,28,1)
    ans = svc.predict(im_final)
    ans = np.argmax(ans,axis=1)[0]
    print(ans)
    cv2.putText(img_orig,'Predicted Digit : '+str(ans),
                    (50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,
                    1,(0,0,255),1)
    cv2.imshow("Original Image",img_orig)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used images of shape 8*8 in your training. For instance;

```
x[0].shape
```

is 64 which is the flattened 8 by 8 array.

However, in your test set you have images of shape 28*28 which causes the problem;

```
im_gray_invert.shape
```

if you had 8*8 images in your test set, by modifying the following line, your code would work;

```
im_final = im_gray_invert.flatten()
```

Hope this helps. Good luck :)